# How to export multiple Azure DevOps Variable Groups?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-cli

We have multiple variable groups in our project and I am trying to find ways how I can export them to my local desktop.

So far I have this az script that exports a variable group but I can only do one at a time. I have several variables and I am trying to do all of them at once. Could someone please help on how I can export multiple variables and use the same name of that variable on Azure DevOps to match it when it's saved on the desktop?

```
az pipelines variable-group show --group-id "id number" --org "https://dev.azure.com/Organization" -p "Project" --output json > test.json
```

Also when I use the script, the value for secret is showing as "null" instead of "false"? Any reason why it's doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To download variable groups in different json file, I've created a script that collects all variable groups, gets their names, and creates folder and files for each variable group. It will create a subfolder VariableGroups in current folder.

```
$ProjectName = "projectName"
$Organization = "https://dev.azure.com/organizationName" 
# Get variable-groups list
$vars = az pipelines variable-group list --organization $Organization --project $ProjectName

# Get variable-groups names list
$v = $vars | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable
$variable_group_names = $v.name

# Go though every variable-group
foreach ($variable_group_name in $variable_group_names) {
    $group = az pipelines variable-group list --organization $Organization --project $ProjectName --group-name $variable_group_name
    
    # Get every variable-group Id
    $g = $group | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable
    $groupId = $g.id
   
    
    # Check if VariableGroups folder exist, if not - create it
    if (!(Test-Path .\VariableGroups)){
        New-Item -itemType Directory -Path .\VariableGroups
    } 
    
    # Get every variable-group content and place it in corresponding folder
    az pipelines variable-group show --organization $Organization --project $ProjectName --id $groupId  --output json>.\VariableGroups\$variable_group_name.json
    Write-Host created .\VariableGroups\$variable_group_name.json
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use below command to export multiple variable groups at a time. See: [az pipelines variable-group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/pipelines/variable-group?view=azure-cli-latest) for details.

`az pipelines variable-group list --org "https://dev.azure.com/Organization" --project "Project" --output json>test.json`

In addition, this secret variable is encrypted in variable group by reference to this doc: [Add & use variable groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic), thus we can only get "null" from return result, which is by design. If you want to use secret variables in Azure Pipelines, please see: [Set secret variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables) for guidance.

Comment: thank you. I have multiple variable groups for example Staging Variable, Production Variable etc. so how can I export them all at once in different json files. The script you provided exports all of them to one json file. Also is there a way that when it exports them, it saves with it's original file name?

Comment: Currently using az command we can only export variable groups to one json file at one time. As a workaround, you could then read the content of json file and write the different variable group to different json file.